# Spin up multiple Vagrant boxes and SSH into them

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have 3 vagrant boxes

```
vagrant box list
```

---

```
hashicorp/precise32 (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
hashicorp/precise64 (vmware_fusion, 1.1.0)
laravel/homestead   (virtualbox, 0.4.2)
```

---

when I do `vagrant up`, and `vagrant ssh`, I kept logged into `hashicorp/precise32` machine.

How do I spin those 3 boxes up at the same time ?

How do I SSH into each of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## vagrant up

will spin up all the vagrant boxes that you have listed in your **Vagrantfile**.

Then, just simple `ssh` into them - one by one.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create Vagrant environments for each of box in three projects folder:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
vagrant init hashicorp/previse64
vagrant init laravel/homestead
```

Now you can use **vagrant up** and **vagrant ssh** in projects folder. Command **vagrant global-status** show you status yours machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can include all three machines in the same vagrantfile and do a single vagrant up inside the directory which will bring up all the machines. Here is a virtualbox example, you may have to edit this and add a vmware provider block to get your laravel machine added.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-

# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

# declare the machine config in a hash
HOST_CONFIG = { 
  'ubuntu_32' => 'hashicorp/precise32',
  'ubuntu_64' => 'hashicorp/previse64',
  'laravel' => 'laravel/homestead'
}

# create the vms
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  HOST_CONFIG.each do |hostname, basebox|
    config.vm.define hostname do |hname|
      hname.vm.box = basebox
      hname.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
        v.name = hostname
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Once the machines are up, inside the same directory you can use the box names you provided in the hash to ssh into each box.

example:

```
vagrant ssh ubuntu_32
```

will take you into hashicorp/precise32 box.

The important part in the vagrantfile that allows you to use a name is

```
config.vm.define hostname do |hname|
```

below block attaches the name to the machine inside virtualbox

```
 hname.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.name = hostname
 end
```

This assign the given name to the attached machine(vm). To get the vmware machine to get a name, you'd probably have to wrap this inside an if-else

```
if hostname == 'ubuntu_64'
  hname.vm.provider 'vmware_fusion' do |v|
    v.name = hostname
  end
else
  hname.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.name = hostname
  end
end
```